# CSS Style Sheet - Menu Bar Issue Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a new web project that needs a CSS menu bar with panel of overview panels on the right side of HTML page. My issue is the that the CSS menu bar style sheet menu does not working. Attempting to get this CSS menu bar working, then extend code functionality for content links, login, dashboard, etc. The entire HTML and CSS below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>   
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<title>Athena Intelligence : Internet of Earth (IoE)</title>
<meta name='description' content=''>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no'>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js'></script>  
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'>
</head>    
<body>        
<header class='header'>
    <div class='header_top-bar'>
        <div class='top-bar_title'>
            <a href='index'><h1><img src='images/logo.png' data-image='images/logo.png' alt='Athena'></h1></a>
            <div class='ajax-loader' id='ajax-loader'>
                <div class='ajax-loader_animator'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='top-bar_toggle' id='menu_toggle'>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class='top-bar_share' id='share_toggle'>
            <span class='underline--white'>
                SHARE
            </span>
        </div> -->
        <div class='top-bar_menu' id='overlay_menu'>
            <ul class='menu_container'>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.01.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/'>Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.02.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/project'>Athena Customers</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.03.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/wines'>Athena Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.04.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/sustainability'>Athena Sustainability</a>
                </li>
                <li class='menu_item'>
                    <span>.05.</span>
                    <a class='link-ajax' href='/hospitality'>Athena Dashboards</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class='language-chooser menu_item'>
                <div class='masi-agricola_wrapper hide-on-mobile'>
                    <a href='http://www.masi.it' target='_blank' class='masi-agricola_link'>
                        <img src='images/agricola.png' data-image='images/agricola.png'/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <p class='text--subtitle'>select your language</p>
                <span class='language-link'><a class='' href='/en/'>Eng</a></span>
                <span class='line-break'></span>
                <span class='language-link'><a class='' href='/es/'>Esp</a></span>
                <span class='line-break'></span>
                <span class='language-link'><a class='' href='/it/'>Ita</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="new-plh" class="plh"></div>
<div id="actual-plh" class="plh">  
    <section class="main-content clearfix homepage">
        <div class="main-content_background">
            <div class="half_screen full-height-desk" id="biggest_block">
                <a href="project" class="">
                    <div class="text-block">
                        <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                            <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                Athena Intelligence Earth's Essential Data
                            </h1>
                            <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                Athena Intelligence Login
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                        <img data-image="images/project-header.jpg" src="images/project-header.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="half_screen full-height-desk">
                <a href="wines">
                    <div class="text-block three_row">
                            <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                    Athena: Many industries: all use Land, Food, Energy, Water
                                </h1>
                                <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                    The Gods: Land, Food, Energy, Water
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img class="three_images" data-image="images/wines-header.jpg" src="images/wines-header.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="sustainability" class="">
                    <div class="text-block three_row">
                            <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                    Land, Food, Energy, Water: Sustainability
                                </h1>
                                <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                    Athena : Dedication To Land, Food, Energy, Water
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img class="three_images" data-image="images/sustainability-header.jpg" src="images/sustainability-header.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="hospitality">
                    <div class="text-block three_row">
                            <div class="full-image_header page-header">
                                <h1 class="page-header_title text--title">
                                    Land, Food, Energy, Water: Hospitality
                                </h1>
                                <strong class="page-header_subtitle text--subtitle">
                                    Land, Food, Energy, Water: That Welcomes You
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img class="three_images" data-image="images/hospitality-header.jpg" src="images/hospitality-header.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <div class='out-loader_wrapper'>
        <div class='out-loader'>
            <div class='filler' id='filler'>
                <img class='logo-loader' src='images/logo.png' data-image='images/logo.png'/>
                <div class='filler-bar'></div>
                <p class='text--title' id='loader_text'>0</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='hidden' id='lang' value='it' />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js')</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS Main file is 211,908 lines and cannot be included in whole. Ask for sections; I will include sections of the pertinent CSS

Comment: can you provide link to your website? Also what is the location of your css file as compared to your html file?

Comment: sometimes a bug can be caused by a minor problem. The only css file that you have included is main.css. Is your menu css in this file or do you have a separate file for your menu css?